# How do you write an if statement in an angular js function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote a function in JS that ran and worked correctly to verify passwords.
I then wrote an identical one in Angular JS and tried to refactor it so it would have the correct bindings and thus and it didn't work.
Im assuming it is possible to do this in Angular, but when I try to google for answers it just takes me to StackOverflow ironically for answers.

Thanks

here is the current javascript if/else statement in the function:
function passwordValidation(){

```
var pwf = document.getElementById("pword1").value;
var pword = document.getElementById("cPassword").value;
var matchCol = "#009900";
var noMatchCol = "#CC0000";
var noBg = "#FFFFFF";
var re = /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[\\\+\=\.,\[\]_£|\`¬':\;\~{}<>()#?!\@$\%^&*-]).{8,20}$/;

if (pwf.length < 1){
        cPassword.style.backgroundColor = noBg;
        cPassword.style.borderColor = noBg;
        match = "";
    }else{

    if (pwf == pword){
        match = "Match!";
        cPassword.style.backgroundColor = matchCol;
        cPassword.style.borderColor = matchCol;
    }else if(pword.length < 1){
        cPassword.style.backgroundColor = noBg;
        cPassword.style.borderColor = noBg;
        match = "";
    }
    else {
    match = "No Match!";
        cPassword.style.backgroundColor = noMatchCol;
        cPassword.style.borderColor = noMatchCol;
    }
    document.getElementById("combination").innerHTML = match;

}
```

angular code attempted: no result returned

```
function passwordValidation($scope){

    $scope.password = "",
    $scope.confPassword = "",
    $scope.isThereAMatch = function(){
        if ($scope.password == $scope.confPassword){
            match = "There is a match!" ;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you will need to provide some code for people to help you.

Comment: @k-nut yep, done. soz

Comment: Still need more context here... is this inside a directive? A controller?

Comment: There also still are variables that we do not know such as `noBg` and `matchCol`

Comment: could you please elaborate your requirement?

Comment: @IsuruSiri i need to write an if statement inside a function in angular js instead of regular js? not sure how I can say anymore than that..

Comment: Where is your Angular JS bit of code you tried?

Comment: @ssilas777 angular code added]

Comment: @ssilas777 so any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Your function is not returning any value. Are you examining 'match' outside the function? If so, then perhaps you want to use $scope.match instead of just match.

Comment: @andrunix that's what I mean though. my function does not return anything in my JS function and so why should it in angular?

Comment: Where is 'match' defined? I don't see it anywhere which means it is within the scope of the function. And thus, unavailable outside the function. Either set it on the $scope ($scope.match = '') or return it from the function. 'return match;'

Comment: @andrunix can you have 2 returns in a func tho?

Comment: @andrunix yeh no luck with the returns or defining match im afraid

Answer (score 3):

Wait, no. You have many issues here:

1. The IF statement is coded as you know - there's no difference in AngularJS.
2. You NEVER alter the DOM in AngularJS. You use directives that set up the styles.
3. Inside each controller, you should have something called `$scope` (yes, with dollar sign). You should set ALL the data there. Let's see an example:

   ```
   //assume this code is inside an ngSubmit/ngClick handler or something like that
   if (pwf.length < 1){
       //cPassword.style.backgroundColor = noBg;
       //cPassword.style.borderColor = noBg;
       $scope.passwordColor = noBg;
       match = "";
   } else {
       if (pwf == pword){
           match = "Match!";
           //cPassword.style.backgroundColor = matchCol;
           //cPassword.style.borderColor = matchCol;
           $scope.passwordColor = matchCol;
       } else if(pword.length < 1){
           //cPassword.style.backgroundColor = noBg;
           //cPassword.style.borderColor = noBg;
           $scope.passwordColor = noMatchCol;
           match = "";
       } else {
           match = "No Match!";
           //cPassword.style.backgroundColor = noMatchCol;
           //cPassword.style.borderColor = noMatchCol;
           $scope.passwordColor = noMatchCol;
       }
       //document.getElementById("combination").innerHTML = match;
       $scope.combination = match;
   }
   ```

AND you HAVE to correctly design your template:

```
<span id="combination">{{ combination }}</span>
...
<input type="password" id="cPassword" ng-style="{'background-color': passwordColor, 'border-color': passwordColor}" />
```

You HAVE to learn many basics or AngularJS and change your paradigm: you NEVER update the DOM properties/structure in a controller, but only in the views (via ng-style) or directives (using jquery/jqlite).

The IF structure is the same as you know, but the altered objects are totally different: you only alter $scope, $rootScope, or call other services in a controller, and NEVER (yes, I say it again) use jquery directly (directives are for that).

Comment: what does the $scope bit actually do in Angular? i have an idea but would be good to be explained in very simplistic terms

Comment: $scope defined the (properly-named) scope of data in the controller. Please, I cannot explain all of that here - in a comment. Is pretty complicated and long, and the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02) explain it pretty well.

Comment: The simplest definition I can think of: It acts as a glue between your view and controller.